# How to send to stdin in bash 10 seconds after starting the process?

Tags: linux, bash

What I want to do is:

- run a process
- wait 10 seconds
- send a string to the stdin of the process

This should be done in a bash script.

I've tried:

```
./script&
pid=$!
sleep 10
echo $string > /proc/${pid}/fd/0
```

It does work in a shell but not when I run it in a script.

Comment: `./script;pid=$!;sleep 10 |echo $string > /proc/${pid}/fd/0`

Comment: And inside a script?

Comment: C.f. my answer below ;-)

Comment: I got a file not found message. the /proc/${pid}/fd/0 doen't seem to exist.

Comment: Are you sure you need to wait? With `echo "$string" | ./script`, the OS buffers the output of `echo` until `script` is actually ready to read it. (Or more accurately, `echo` blocks *until* `script` tries to read from its standard input.)

Comment: My script reads from stdin right from the start and waits fot the string "quit" to stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
( sleep 10; echo "how you doin?" ) | ./script
```

Your approach might work on Linux if e.g., your scripts stdin is e.g., something like a FIFO:

```
myscript(){ tr a-z A-Z; }
rm -f p
mkfifo p
exec 3<>p
myscript <&3 &
pid=$!
echo :waiting
sleep 0.5
echo :writing
file /proc/$pid/fd/0
echo hi > /proc/$pid/fd/0
exec 3>&-
```

But this `/proc/$pid/fd` stuff behaves differently on different Unices.

It doesn't work for your case because your scripts stdin is a terminal.
With default terminal settings, the terminal driver will put background proccesses trying to read from it to sleep (by sending them the SIGTTIN signal) and writes to a terminal filedescriptor will just get echoed -- they won't wake up the sleeping background process that's was put to sleep trying to read from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

What about this (as OP requested it to be done in the script):

```
#! /bin/bash
./script&
pid=$!
sleep 10
echo $string > /proc/${pid}/fd/0
```

just proposing the missing element not commenting on coding style ;-)